# Django: can't inspectdb second database

Tags: python, django, database, manage.py, inspectdb

I have the following 2 databases in my DATABASES dictionary:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'C:/Users/B/Desktop/board.db'
    },
    'game':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'C:/Users/B/Desktop/gamelogic.db'
    },
}
```

I'm having trouble doing `inspectdb` on the second database 'game'.

I tried to do: `python manage.py inspectdb --database 'game'`
but I'm getting the error `django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection 'game' doesn't exist` even though the database exists. How do I inspectdb a non-default database?

Answer (score 3):

Use this command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database=game > your_app/models.py
```